# Trouble binding INT to PDO prepared statement for LIMIT and OFFSET

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm having trouble binding an INT value to my PDO prepared statement.  It's passing the INTs as strings, `''`s and all.  I need to bind INTs for my LIMIT and OFFSET in the SQL query.

Here's my code:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM post WHERE private = 0 ORDER BY post_time DESC LIMIT :number_results OFFSET :offset");
$sth->execute(array(':number_results' => $number_results, ':offset' => $offset));
$errors = $sth->errorInfo();
    print_r($errors[2]);
```

I'm receiving `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''20' OFFSET '0'' at line 1`

I found [this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44639) bug report, but have not had any luck so far with the comments.  How can I bind these values?

Edit: When I try to set the param type, I don't get any errors, but it doesn't look like it's binding the correct parameters?

```
Params:  2
Key: Name: [15] :number_results
paramno=-1
name=[15] ":number_results"
is_param=1
param_type=1
Key: Name: [7] :offset
paramno=-1
name=[7] ":offset"
is_param=1
param_type=1
```

Comment: You are sure that $number_results is an int that is 20 and not a string that is '20'? Try to cast it to an int

Comment: @WizKid: I did add (int)$number_results as the bind param, but got the same thing.  `var_dump($number_results)` is int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind parameters and specify the data type using [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). In your case you want to tell PDO the value is an integer using `PDO::PARAM_INT`.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM post WHERE private = 0 ORDER BY post_time DESC LIMIT :number_results OFFSET :offset");

// Bind params
$sth->bindParam(':number_results', $number_results, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$sth->execute();
$errors = $sth->errorInfo();
    print_r($errors[2]);
```

Because you've specified the parameters individually, there is no need to pass them through as an array in your `$sth->execute();` call.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I had tried this before as well, please see my edit to my post.  Am I misreading the debug or are the parameters not being set correctly?

Comment: Nope, I'm an idiot.  Forgot to put `$sth->execute();` back in after changing to the bindParam.  Sorry for the wasted question.  It has been answered elsewhere on the site.  Still would be nice to see it fixed.

Comment: My suggestion would be to bump the bug by posting your PHP and MySQL version details and a snippet of code you ran to replicate the issue so people can see it's still relevant and hopefully prioritise it. Especially with more and more people switching to PDO/MySQLi.